# Method from main class is getting called for Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, powermockito

I am writing a test class for one of the method in my class. I can't make much changes in the class. Below is a simpler version of my code.

```
Class AInternal extend A {
    public List getList(listArg1, listArg2)  {
        boolean flag = isCorrectFlag();
        if (flag)  {
            return getListForNext(nextArg1, nextArg2);
        }
    }

    public boolean isCorrectFlag(){
        //logic and return value
    }

    protected List getListForNext(nextArg1, nextArg2)   {
        AIteror arit = new AIterator();
        String s  = fetchValue();
        arit.getObject();
    }

    protected class AIterator  {
        public Iterator getObject() {
            //logic and return iterator
        }
    }

}

Class A {
    public  String fetchValue() {
        //logic and return value
    }
}
```

Below is my test method

```
@Test
public void getList() throws Exception {
    try {
      AInternal AInternalSpy = spy(new AInternal());
      AIterator AIteratorSpy = spy(AInternal.new AIterator());
      Iterator<Object> iterator1 = ep.iterator();
      doReturn(Boolean.TRUE).when(AInternalSpy).isCorrectFlag();
      doReturn("value").when(AInternalSpy).fetchValue();
      doReturn(iterator1).when(AIterator).getObject();
      
      AInternalSpy.getIteratorPartitions(arg1, arg2);

    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      throw new Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

The first two doReturn 's are returning correct values but getObject() method is calling the method from the class and is not returning the stubbed value.
I tried returning mock instance by using PowerMockito.whenNew but that did not work.
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: you can't mock like that. If you want to mock it, make that service a field in the class, not a local one in the method, where you initialize it

Comment: @Stultuske why are first two correctly correctly returning stubbed values?

Comment: Seeing as you didn't include the relevant code about that, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the new instance creation into a new function like this:

```
protected AIterator getIteratorInstance() {
    return new AIterator();
}
```

Now, you can modify getListForNext(...) function to:

```
protected List getListForNext(nextArg1, nextArg2)   {
    AIteror arit = getIteratorInstance();
    String s  = fetchValue();
    arit.getObject();
}
```

Now return a mock or a spy of AIterator for the newly created getIteratorInstance() function:

```
doReturn(AIteratorSpy).when(AInternalSpy).getIteratorInstance()
```

Your test should execute now.